# Youtube API - Get duration of videos from a playlist

Tags: php, optimization, foreach, google-api, youtube-api

I need to get the duration of all the videos in a Youtube playlist.
I know that the API does not show me the duration of each video when doing the search of all, but it does show it if the query is made for a particular video.

Through PHP I tried to collect all the IDs from the playlist and then analyze each ID to get the data from the videos, but the script is too slow, although it should be stressed that it works well, is there any way to optimize it?...

```
    function youtube_automusic($listas, $api_key, $resultados){
        $nresultados = $resultados;
        $lista_reproduccion_random = $listas;
        $lista_reproduccion = $lista_reproduccion_random[array_rand($lista_reproduccion_random)];
        $url_playlist = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&fields=items(snippet(resourceId(videoId)))&type=video&videoCategoryId=10&maxResults=".$nresultados."&playlistId=".$lista_reproduccion."&key=".$api_key;
        $data = dlPage($url_playlist);
        $data_decode = json_decode($data, true);

        $number_song = 1;
        $respuesta = array();
        foreach ($data_decode as $items){
            foreach ($items as $item){
                $lista_ids =$item['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'];
                $url_video = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=".$lista_ids."&part=snippet,contentDetails&fields=items(etag,id,snippet(publishedAt,title,thumbnails(default(url)),tags),contentDetails(duration))&key=".$api_key;
                $data_video = dlPage($url_video);
                $data_video_decode = json_decode($data_video, true);
                foreach ($data_video_decode as $items_videos){
                    foreach ($items_videos as $item_video){
                        $data_final = array(
                            'etag' => $item_video['etag'],
                            'idvideo' => $item_video['id'],
                            'titulovideo' => $item_video['snippet']['title'],
                            'thumbnail' => $item_video['snippet']['thumbnails']['default']['url'],
                            'duracion' => $item_video['contentDetails']['duration'],
                            'videoplay' => $number_song++
                        );
                        array_push($respuesta, $data_final);
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
        return json_encode($respuesta);         
    }
```

Comment: May i suggest you check out the Google PHP client library.

Comment: What does your `dlPage()` look like?

Comment: Its a function that use simple_html_dom

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With your code on a 50 item playlist it would take 51 API calls.

Instead of doing a single videos request for each video in the playlist, get all the video IDs in the playlist first and then make videos requests for up to 50 at a time (the ID parameter takes a comma-separated list of up to 50 items).

Then a 50 item playlist would only take 2 API calls.

Should be much faster.

Comment: I really did not know that you could enter several IDs with a separation comma, now I can optimize my function, thanks!

Comment: Does quota counts as one request if you list videos comma-separated?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran a test [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=snippet%252CcontentDetails&id=Ks-_Mh1QhMc&fields=items(etag%252Cid%252Csnippet(publishedAt%252Ctitle%252Cthumbnails(default(url))%252Ctags)%252CcontentDetails(duration))&_h=1&)

Request:

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&id=Ks-_Mh1QhMc&fields=items(etag%2Cid%2Csnippet(publishedAt%2Ctitle%2Cthumbnails(default(url))%2Ctags)%2CcontentDetails(duration))&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Results:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "etag": "\"RmznBCICv9YtgWaaa_nWDIH1_GM/aCBUdsaX0W34z3It8a8FCh5uteo\"",
   "id": "Ks-_Mh1QhMc",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2012-10-01T15:27:35.000Z",
    "title": "Your body language may shape who you are | Amy Cuddy",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Ks-_Mh1QhMc/default.jpg"
     }
    },
    "tags": [
     "Amy Cuddy",
     "TED",
     "TEDTalk",
     "TEDTalks",
     "TED Talk",
     "TED Talks",
     "TEDGlobal",
     "brain",
     "business",
     "psychology",
     "self",
     "success"
    ]
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT21M3S"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

I suggest that you run the same request using the Google APIs Explorer using the video id that you are having an issue with to verify that its not an issue with the API not returning your duration.

Comment: The script works well, the problem is that Im trying get the video duration from a playlist. However playlist not show video duration so, I was trying first get all videoID from playlist, then get video details from every videoID found. It work but the script is so slow because this have to do multi parse.

Comment: @Kokox have you found any way to achieve this?